# Transition a property after it has been animated

Tags: css, animation

I have an element that comes in from the left when it's added to the page (from an XHR call):

```
.flyin:not(.animation_done) {
    -webkit-animation: flyin .5s ease forwards;

    margin-left: -210px;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flyin {
    to { 
        margin-left: 0;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

But I would like to animate the `margin-left` property on hover:

```
.element_im_animating.animation_done {
    margin-left: 0;
    transition: margin-left .4s ease;
}

.element_im_animating.mod.animation_done:hover {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

To accomplish this I am adding a class when the animation finishes:

```
$(document).on("animationend webkitAnimationEnd", function(e) {
    $(e.target).addClass("animation_done");
});
```

Strangely, adding `animation_done` is triggering the `flyin` animation *a second time* straight after it finishes. Can I stop this happening? Is there a simpler no-javascript way to do what I need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The animation isn't running a *second* time.

What is really happening is the following:

Your element has the margin set like this:

```
.flyin:not(.animation_done) {
    margin-left: -210px;
}
```

And the end of the animation has a margin-left of 0px because of this

```
.flyin:not(.animation_done) {
    -webkit-animation: flyin 5s ease forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flyin {
    to { 
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
}
```

When you remove the animation, no longer applies the **forwards** rule above, and the margin is now the default one (-210px). Since this property is *transitioned* (not animated !), it will move to the new value:

```
.animation_done {
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

in a similar way to the animation. Solve it setting the base margin to the final one, and not using *forwards*

```
.flyin:not(.animation_done) {
    -webkit-animation: flyin 5s ease;

    margin-left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flyin {
    from { 
        margin-left: -210px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to { 
        margin-left: 0px;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.animation_done {
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: margin-left 4s ease;
}

.animation_done:hover {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/jtBHL/)